# Mulesoftt community edition. is it discontinued?

Tags: integration, mulesoft

I could not find the link to download the mulesoft community edition, so I was wondering is it discontinued? if not from where I can download it?
another question is good for integration between two saas platforms?

Comment: "another question is good for integration between two saas platforms?" this is a complete separate question. Please provide a lot of detail if you post it or it may be closed as opinion based or not belonging to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still find the link to download as Mule Kernel: https://developer.mulesoft.com/download-mule-esb-runtime

> Mule Kernel (without Anypoint Studio) Download if you are:
>
> - Comfortable editing XML directly
> - Not looking for a graphical modeling and testing environment
> - Have already created and tested a Mule application and you need to deploy in a separate Mule standalone runtime

Comment: Thanks alot .. can I use this kernel for integrating two saas systems?

Comment: That's an unrelated question, and also a very broad one. See my comment to your question above.