# We get java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in Mule ESB while we try to do jaxb-object-to-xml-transformer

Tags: jaxb, mule, mule-esb

In Mule 3.9.0, while we are trying to convert an object to XML  using jaxb, we are getting the below error

```
Message               : null (java.util.ConcurrentModificationException)
Element               : /test/processors/0 @ test-masked:masked.xml:685 (JAXB Object to JMSMessage (XML string))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
null (java.util.ConcurrentModificationException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
  java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
  com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister$1.next(Lister.java:284)
  com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:135)
  com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:155)
  com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
  com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
  com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:152)
  com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
  com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
  com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:152)
  com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
  com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:593)
  com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:324)
  com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:494)
  com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:315)
  com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:244)
  javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:116)
  org.mule.module.xml.transformer.jaxb.JAXBMarshallerTransformer.doTransform(JAXBMarshallerTransformer.java:77)
  org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:415)
  org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:366)
  (40 more...)
```

The place where we try to convert is in an asynchronous call as below

```
<async>


<mulexml:jaxb-object-to-xml-transformer
                    returnClass="java.lang.String" mimeType="text/xml"
                    jaxbContext-ref="JAXB_Context_Update_Journey"/>

<logger
                    message="#[message:correlationId] | pushing to cache.inbox -payload - #[payload]"
                    level="INFO" category="update cache" />
 </async>
```

Project wants us to stick with community version and hence we can't upgrade to 4 +

With the given situation, how do we resolve this? Without  it was working fine. After we changed to asynchronous this issue started. We also upgraded to Mule 3.9.5, but still the same issue.

Comment: Why are you trying to use that async? Note that there is no Mule 3.9.6. Please fix the version in the question. Why you don't migrate to Mule 4 community edition?

Comment: Hi Aled, Changed to 3.9.5.
We are using the async to perform parallel processing. While a part of the flow updates a queue, a parallel flow will update into a cache. This is the process we are trying to achieve using async

Comment: What is the payload content and class?

Comment: The payload content is a very big XML chunk, for which we have JAXB classes generated. We are trying to convert this object to text before we post inside a cache or queue.

Answer (score 0):

The exception ConcurrentModificationException and the stacktrace indicates that a list was modified concurrently. It seems that the `async` thread and the original thread of the flow are using the payload at the same time and that causes the error. You could resolve the issue by creating a clone of the input payload. But that probably will be the same as converting the payload in the original thread anyway.

Mule 4 may have better handling of this kind of situations with the feature of targeting operations to variables instead of the payload and isolation, however you would need to migrate your application and see how your use case works there.

Comment: Cloning of the payload seems interesting, I will do a little investigation on it. I would love to go for Mule-4 but, we are allowed to go with community edition only. Can we take Mule 4 CE for production. We don't mind to have a support for it, as we need client to decide on it.

Comment: Licensing/support questions are off topic for Stackoverflow. This answer may be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69257010/mulesoftt-community-edition-is-it-discontinued

Answer (score 0):

It is closed. I couldn't upgrade. But still, I found a logical way within my flow to resolve this. Avoided async call before jaxb transformation. I called the asynch flow only after transforming